# SQL Server 2016 Json result structure to array

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

This is my table and data

[image]

My Query:

```
SELECT [Name]
  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[MyCategory]
 WHERE [Category] = 'A'
   FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

```
[
   {"Name": "John"},
   {"Name": "Mary"},
   {"Name": "Dick"}
]
```

But I want to get the result like:

```
["John", "Mary", "Dick"]
```

Comment: Look at  Magne Rekdal's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708638/sql-to-json-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values-in-sql-2016

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @stra varchar (200)
set @stra = ''

select  top 5 @stra = 
    case when @stra = ''
    then '["'+ Name
    else @stra + coalesce('","' + Name, '')
    end
  from [TestDB].[dbo].[MyCategory]

  set @stra= @stra +'"]'
print @stra
```

Comment: `SELECT @v = @v + ...` could be undefined and it is not safe method for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this JSON format is supported in `FOR JSON` clause, see [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/convert-sql-server-results-json/), although the string `["John","Mary","Dick"]` is considered valid json using ISJSON function.

Your only way probably would be to modify the output yourself like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @MyCategory TABLE (ID int , Category char(1), [Name] varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @MyCategory VALUES (1, 'A', 'John')
INSERT INTO @MyCategory VALUES (2, 'A', 'Mary')
INSERT INTO @MyCategory VALUES (3, 'A', 'Dick')
INSERT INTO @MyCategory VALUES (4, 'B', 'Sam')

DECLARE @MyJSON varchar(max) 
SELECT @MyJSON =
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
(
 SELECT [Name] AS ReplaceMe
  FROM @MyCategory
 WHERE [Category] = 'A'
   FOR JSON AUTO
   ), '{"ReplaceMe":',''
   ) , '}','')

PRINT @MyJSON
PRINT ISJSON(@MyJSON)
```

Outputs to:

```
["John","Mary","Dick"]
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Magne Rekdal's answer to [SQL to JSON - array of objects to array of values in SQL 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708638/sql-to-json-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values-in-sql-2016)

```
SELECT REPLACE(
          REPLACE((
               SELECT [Name]
               FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[MyCategory]
               WHERE [Category] = 'A'
               FOR JSON AUTO), '{"Name":','')
               '}','')
```