# Sql Query to get an array having no column name in json result

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following fields

```
 Id     RequestId     CategoryId
 1      112           1
 2      123           1
 3      123           2

SELECT      R.RequestId,
            (SELECT RC.CategoryId FROM Request RC WHERE RC.Id = R.Id FOR JSON AUTO) AS Categories
FROM        Request R
```

Above query returns the data as mentioned below

```
 RequestId     Categories
 112           [{"CategoryId":"1"}]
 123           [{"CategoryId":"1"},{"CategoryId":"2"}]
```

But, I want that column name **CategoryId** should not be repeated for every item in json array. Thus, my expected result is:

```
 RequestId     Categories
 112           ["1"]
 123           ["1","2"]
```

Comment: Hi, what was the best solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Was used: [SQL to JSON - array of objects to array of values in SQL 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708638/sql-to-json-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values-in-sql-2016)

> ```
> create table Request (
>   Id int,
>   RequestId int,
>   CategoryId int
> )
> GO
> ```

> ```
> insert into Request (Id,RequestId,CategoryId) values
> ( 1,      112,           1),
> ( 2,      123,           1),
> ( 3,      123,           2);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT distinct R.RequestId,
>             (
> SELECT  
>   JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF(( SELECT ',' + '"' + convert(varchar(10), RC.CategoryId) + '"' 
> FROM Request RC
> WHERE RC.RequestId = R.RequestId
> FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']' ) Categories  
> FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
>             ) AS Categories
> FROM Request R
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> RequestId | Categories              
> --------: | :-----------------------
>       112 | {"Categories":["1"]}    
>       123 | {"Categories":["1","2"]}
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  distinct R.RequestId,
>
> JSON_QUERY(
>             (
> SELECT  
>   JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF(( SELECT ',' + '"' + convert(varchar(10), RC.CategoryId) + '"' 
> FROM Request RC
> WHERE RC.RequestId = R.RequestId
> FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']' ) Categories  
> FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
>             )
> , '$.Categories' )
> FROM Request R
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> RequestId | (No column name)
> --------: | :---------------
>       112 | ["1"]           
>       123 | ["1","2"]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=547ceee13c49b5f3a7003a4b50c96296)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, STUFF makes query execution really very slow when data is huge. Any thoughts about it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you need to aggregate string yourself and then convert it to json. For example, in Sql Server 2017 you can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select
    t.RequestId,
    concat('[',string_agg(t.CategoryId, ','),']') as Categories
from Table1 as t
group by
    t.RequestId
```

[<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ddc77/2)

If you need your array values to be strings instead of integers you can then you need to add `"` char manually and you also might want to use [`STRING_ESCAPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so special characters will be converted safely:

```
select
    t.RequestId,
    concat('[',string_agg(concat('"', string_escape(t.CategoryId, 'json'),'"'),','),']') as Categories
from Table1 as t
group by
    t.RequestId
```

[<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ae78/1)

In yearlier versions of Sql Server you can either use xml trick or create custom clr aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using REPLACE:

```
 declare @test table ([Id] int, [RequestId] int, [CategoryId] int)
 insert into @test values
   (1, 112, 1)
 , (2, 123, 1)
 , (3, 123, 2)

    SELECT      R.RequestId,
                json_query(replace(replace((SELECT RC.CategoryId FROM @test RC WHERE RC.Id = R.Id FOR JSON AUTO), '{"CategoryId":', '"'), '}','"'))  AS Categories
    FROM        @test R
```

Answer (score 0):

For sample table

```
SELECT Id,RequestId,CategoryId INTO #Request FROM ( values
( 1,      112,           '1'),
( 2,      123,           '1'),
( 3,      123,           '2'))v(Id,RequestId,CategoryId)
;
```

You can perform a recursive query

```
 WITH S AS (
    SELECT RequestId,CategoryId,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition BY RequestId ORDER BY CategoryId DESC) _LP FROM  #Request
    )
    , C AS (
    SELECT s.RequestId,JSON_MODIFY('[]','append $',s.CategoryId)w,s._lp
    FROM (SELECT RequestId,MAX(_LP)_MLP FROM S GROUP BY RequestId) S1
    INNER JOIN S ON s.RequestId=s1.RequestId AND s._LP=s1._MLP
    union ALL
    SELECT s.RequestId,JSON_MODIFY(c.w,'append $',s.CategoryId)w,s._lp
    FROM  S
    inner join C ON s.RequestId=c.RequestId and s._LP=c._lp-1
    )
    SELECT RequestId,W Categories FROM C WHERE _LP=1
```

You will receive the result:

```
RequestId   Categories
----------- --------------------
112         ["1"]
123         ["1","2"]
```