# For JSON Path Formatting

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

**Background:**

I have a JSON `nvarchar(max)` column named 'questions' that looks like this real example from a single row...

```
{"211":0,"212":0,"213":0,"214":0,"215":0,"216":0,"217":0,"218":0,"219":0,"220":"1","221":"1","222":"1","223":"1","224":"1","225":"1","226":"1","227":"1","228":"1","229":"1","230":"1","231":"1","232":"1"}
```

I'm currently generating this example JSON snippet for an example 'call'...

```
[
  {
    "call": {
      "id": 200643,
      "yes_answers": [
        {
          "question_id": "220"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "221"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "222"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "223"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "224"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "225"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "226"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "227"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "228"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "229"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "230"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "231"
        },
        {
          "question_id": "232"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

.. using this query...

```
select c.call_id as [call.id],
    (
        select x.[key]
        from [call].[triage_questions] tq
            cross apply openjson(questions, '$') as x
        where value = 1 and tq.call_id = c.call_id
        for json path
    ) as [call.yes_answers]
from [call].[dimension] c
where call_id = 200643
for json path
```

**My Question:**

I don't like the way the "yes_answers" array is being formatted. I'd like something more like this:

```
[
  {
    "call": {
      "id": 200643,
      "yes_answers": [
        220,
        221,
        222,
        223,
        224,
        225,
        226,
        227,
        228,
        229,
        230,
        231,
        232
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Is this valid? or should I be rolling this up a different way? or just leave it?

I'll be using SQL to reference each question_id in the "yes_answers" array to a reference table where I'm looking for a true/false flag associated with that question. The JSON will not be leaving SQL at this time, if that matters.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [@Tomato32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3753686/tomato32), I've found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708638/sql-to-json-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values-in-sql-2016) that helped me get close enough, I think.

My query now looks like this...

```
select c.call_id as [call.id],
    json_query(replace(replace((
        select x.[key] as question_id
        from [call].[triage_questions] tq
            cross apply openjson(questions, '$') as x
        where value = 1 and tq.call_id = c.call_id
        order by x.[key]
        for json path
    ), N'{"question_id":', N''), '"}', '"')) as [call.yes_answers]
from [call].[dimension] c
where call_id = 200643
for json path
```

And my resulting JSON looks like this...

```
[
  {
    "call": {
      "id": 200643,
      "yes_answers": [
        "220",
        "221",
        "222",
        "223",
        "224",
        "225",
        "226",
        "227",
        "228",
        "229",
        "230",
        "231",
        "232"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I can't get rid of the quotes around the int values in the "yes_answers" array, but I don't think it's going to matter, and I'm not going to waste any time on it :) Thank you all!!!

Comment: I think you can use STUFF and FOR XML PATH for this.

Comment: Tim, great, that you found a solution yourself! You might add this as an answer and accept it. Might be you get [the *self-learner*-badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20544/how-to-earn-the-self-learner-badge). And it might help to cast your `[key]` as `INT`. *Naked* numbers are placed in JSON without quotes normally...

Comment: Did you check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only updated your replace statements to get rid of the quotation marks in "[number]", as below:-

```
select c.call_id as [call.id],
    json_query(replace(replace((
        select x.[key] as question_id
        from [call].[triage_questions] tq
            cross apply openjson(questions, '$') as x
        where value = 1 and tq.call_id = c.call_id
        order by x.[key]
        for json path
    ), N'{"question_id":"', N''), '"}', '')) as [call.yes_answers]
from [call].[dimension] c
where call_id = 200643
for json path
```

In my testing, the output is as below:-

```
[{"call":{"id":200643,"yes_answers":[220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232]}}]
```