# SQL Server Split delimited String to JSON Array

Tags: json, sql-server

Server : SQL Server 2016

I am trying to split a delimited string in one column in DB to JSON Array for easy joins in ETL Job

```
shirt|~*~|trouser|~*~|t-Shirt|~*~|towels|~*~|
```

into JSON Value

```
   {"values":["shirt", "trouser", "t-Shirt", "towels"]}
```

One of the article I followed here helped a little, but could not get me far enough, I want to convert using select instead of procedure/function

Any Pointers is helpful

[SQL to JSON - array of objects to array of values in SQL 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708638/sql-to-json-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values-in-sql-2016/37844117#37844117)

Comment: Do you have to do this in SQL Server?  I mean, it would be much easier to handle unnormalized CSV data somewhere like C# or Java than in a database.

Comment: We are reading the Data from SQL Views in Batch Jobs as a part of ETL

Comment: OK, any time you find yourself pulling in large amounts of CSV data into your database, it might be time to step back and question your pipeline.

Comment: Why is there a delimiter at the end? Shouldn't it therefore be `'{"values":["shirt", "trouser", "t-Shirt", "towels",""]}'`?

Comment: The Delimited string is a part of DB which legacy, I cannot get the weird delimited string into Master DB as its of no use, at least with JSON array, I can cross join

Comment: I think "step back and question your pipeline" should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `REPLACE` would be better option here:

```
DECLARE @CSV varchar(MAX) = 'shirt|~*~|trouser|~*~|t-Shirt|~*~|towels|~*~|';

SELECT '{"values":["' + REPLACE(V.csv,'|~*~|','","') + '"]}'
FROM (VALUES(@CSV))V(csv);
```