# How to Get list of ids from same query when returning as JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

`apps` table

```
app_id  |   app_name   |  app_status
-------------------------------------
  1         scheduling    INACTIVE
  2         call          ACTIVE
  3         billing       ACTIVE
  4         order         ACTIVE
```

I have a query,

`SELECT * FROM apps WHERE app_status = "ACTIVE" FOR JSON PATH;`

This query has an `app_id` field. I also want a field to accompany the `json` output with a field `ids` with all the `app_id` as a list.

So instead of:

```
[{
    "app_id": 2,
    "app_name": "call",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
}, {
    "app_id": 3,
    "app_name": "billing",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
}, {
    "app_id": 4,
    "app_name": "order",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
}]
```

I would have:

```
[{
    "apps": [{
        "app_id": 2,
        "app_name": "call",
        "status": "ACTIVE"
    }, {
        "app_id": 3,
        "app_name": "billing",
        "status": "ACTIVE"
    }, {
        "app_id": 4,
        "app_name": "order",
        "status": "ACTIVE"
    }],
    "ids": [2, 3, 4]
}]
```

Comment: Why Microsoft don't have a simple solution for this is beyond me, it seems to be a common requirement. Some version of `JSON_QUERY( STUFF( ... FOR XML PATH('') ) )` is popular, such as this previous [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708638/sql-to-json-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values-in-sql-2016).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns the correct JSON

Data

```
drop table if exists dbo.tTable;
go
create table dbo.tTable(
  app_id            int not null,
  [app_name]        nvarchar(200),
  app_status        nvarchar(200));

insert dbo.tTable(app_id, app_name, app_status) values
(1, 'scheduling', 'INACTIVE'),
(2, 'call', 'ACTIVE'),
(3, 'billing', 'ACTIVE'),
(4, 'order', 'ACTIVE');
```

Query

```
with active_cte as (
    select * FROM tTable WHERE app_status = 'ACTIVE')
SELECT 
  (select * FROM active_cte FOR JSON PATH) apps,
  (select JSON_QUERY(concat('[',string_agg(app_id, ','),']'),'$') from active_cte) ids
for json path;
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "apps": [
      {
        "app_id": 2,
        "app_name": "call",
        "app_status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "app_id": 3,
        "app_name": "billing",
        "app_status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "app_id": 4,
        "app_name": "order",
        "app_status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "ids": [ 2, 3, 4 ]
  }
]
```