# JSON result format incorrect

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve JSON from SQL Server using `FOR JSON PATH` that looks like this:

```
["5.0","5.5","6.0","6.5","7.0","7.5","8.0","8.5","9.0","9.5","10.0","10.5","11.0"]
```

But I am getting this instead:

```
[{"value":"10.0"},{"value":"10.5"},{"value":"11.0"},{"value":"5.0"},{"value":"5.5"},{"value":"6.0"},{"value":"6.5"},{"value":"7.0"},{"value":"7.5"},{"value":"8.0"},{"value":"8.5"},{"value":"9.0"},{"value":"9.5"}]
```

```
SELECT        [value]
FROM          [table]
FOR JSON PATH

DECLARE @json_test TABLE ([value] varchar(5))
INSERT INTO @json_test values ('5.0')
INSERT INTO @json_test values ('6.0')
INSERT INTO @json_test values ('7.0')
INSERT INTO @json_test values ('8.0')
INSERT INTO @json_test values ('9.0')
INSERT INTO @json_test values ('10.0')

SELECT [value]
FROM @json_test
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL to JSON - array of objects to array of values in SQL 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708638/sql-to-json-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values-in-sql-2016)

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2017 and later, where [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) is available...

```sql
with Concatenated (someText) as (
  select string_agg(quotename([value], '"'), ',')
  from @json_test
)
select someArray = json_query(quotename(someText))
from Concatenated
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```

Which yields...

```
{"someArray":["5.0","6.0","7.0","8.0","9.0","10.0"]}
```

Comment: Instead of `quotename` use `STRING_ESCAPE(..., 'json')`

Comment: How would `string_escape()` help? I'm not replacing or escaping characters with `quote_name()`, I'm using it as a lazy man's `concat()`.

Comment: I assumed you used it to also escape `"` in the values, but it doesn't work properly for json. Best way to do it is `string_agg(cast('"' + string_escape([value], 'json') + '"' as nvarchar(max)), ',')` admittedly it matters less with the current input, but it is `varchar` so it could have anything in there