Format JSON with comma separated value
Table 1: Purchases



ClientID
ItemID




1234
1,2


5678
3,4



create table Purchases (ClientId int, ItemId varchar(128));

insert into Purchases (ClientId, ItemId)
values
(1234, '1,2'),
(5678, '3,4');

Declare @newtable table(
    clientid NVARCHAR(MAX),
    itemid NVARCHAR(MAX),
    json NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

insert into @newtable
select [ClientID], [ItemID],'{}'
From Purchases;

Update @newtable
Set Json = JSON_MODIFY (Json, '$.ItemID', [ItemID]);

select * from @newtable;

I tried using Json_modify and I got { "ItemID": "1,2"} for client id 1234, but I want to JSON output to be { "ItemID": [ "1", "2" ]}
I am expecting the following



ClientID
ItemID
Json




1234
1,2
{   "ItemID": [      "1",      "2"      ]}


5678
3,4
{   "ItemID": [      "3",      "4"      ]}




First you string_split your ItemID, then you https://stackoverflow.com/q/37708638/11683.

Just to confirm... you're expecting [ "1", "2" ] strings as opposed to [ 1, 2 ] numbers?

@AlwaysLearning correct

Since the values are already in a comma-separated list, there is no need to split and then recombine the values. You can brute force the list to a JSON array with a replace and some concatenation.
SELECT
    P.*,
    CONCAT(
       '{ "ItemID": [ "',
       REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(P.ItemId, 'json'), ',', '", "'),
       '" ]}'
       ) AS Json
FROM Purchases P

The STRING_ESCAPE() function handles potential embedded double quotes.
Results:



ClientId
ItemId
Json




1234
1,2
{ "ItemID": [ "1", "2" ]}


5678
3,4
{ "ItemID": [ "3", "4" ]}



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

You can use
JSON_QUERY - extract json array from a string
JSON AUTO - transform the result into json
REPLACE for double quotes (added)
SELECT ClientId,JSON_QUERY('["'+REPLACE(ItemId,',','","')+'"]') as ItemID
  FROM Purchases
   FOR JSON AUTO

complete solution
